# MailGun Get Unsubscribes

Tags: php, curl, mailgun

I am using PHP's CURL function to return all unsubscribed emails in my domain using MailGun. I tried the following code:

```
function get_unsubscriptions() {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:key-[key removed]');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/[domain removed]/unsubscriptions');

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

But it only returns the following:

> Mailgun Magnificent API

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing else to the error like "Unexpected token"? Have you considered looking at their SDK? Also: [Php - Debugging Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl)

Comment: That's the thing, it isn't an error. The message is what is returned from `$result`. I've looked at their documentation but it only relates to their API (as opposed to using cURL), however everything looks like it matches up.

Comment: Is it really `unsubscriptions`? Pretty sure that isn't a word. Maybe `unsubscribes`?

Comment: The endpoint is `unsubscribes` not `unsubscriptions`.  [See Here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-suppressions.html#view-all-unsubscribes).  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: That was it, gosh I'm dumb...

Comment: They could give you a better error message honestly.